# Is there a way to make drawing object in google sheet stays always in front (top)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, format, drawing

I have 2 drawing object in my google sheet, 1st drawing stays stationary and the 2nd moves when a value from a cell changes. My problem is when the row anchor changes to row 50 onwards the 2nd drawing moves behind the 1st drawing.
[image]
[image]

I tried searching if this could be done using macro but could not find any. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Code from comment below.

```
function moveDrawing(){ 
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LAYOUT"); 
  const range = sheet.getRange("B12").getValue(); 
  const obj = { 1: {name: " Drawing1 ", moveTo: [14,4]}, 
                2: {name: " Drawing2 ", moveTo: [(range*0.5)+14,4]} }; 
  sheet.getDrawings() .forEach( d => { 
      const dwg = d.getZIndex(); 
      if (dwg in obj) { d.setPosition(...obj[dwg].moveTo,0,0); } 
    } 
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried playing with the [z index](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing#setZIndex(Number))?

Comment: Yes i did use the z index. My code below;

Comment: function moveDrawing(){
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LAYOUT");
  const range = sheet.getRange("B12").getValue();

  const obj = {
                1: {name: " Drawing1 ", moveTo: [14,4]},
                2: {name: " Drawing2 ", moveTo: [(range*0.5)+14,4]}
              };
  
  sheet.getDrawings()
    .forEach(d => {
      const dwg = d.getZIndex();
      if (dwg in obj) {
        d.setPosition(...obj[dwg].moveTo,0,0);
      }
    }  
  )
}